# How to change the view of the geometry type column in the DataGrip?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, datagrip

English is not my first language, so please point out any mistakes.

I am using PostgreSQL with postgis installed.

My table DDL:

```sql
create table geo_teble
(
    latitude     numeric(12, 8),
    longitude    numeric(12, 8),
    geom         public.geometry
);
```

The geometry data in my table usually looks like raw data.

| longitude | latitude | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 127.72793149 | 34.91585546 | 01060000000200000001030000000100000005000000F98E01A8F9E75F40B6F82F508A7241400AFEEE1D15E95F400D3342544F704140F142F81C05ED5F4086EE0258817541405720CDB729EC5F405FCE129181774140F98E01A8F9E75F40B6F82F508A7241400103000000010000000600000065272DFF0AED5F40020C3E8F66744140A47C9CA128ED5F407E957D764677414072D3174DBFF05F40C10D3CEA4A7B4140C6187A10A9F25F404A3772A60375414057914A1BC3F25F409EA685118270414065272DFF0AED5F40020C3E8F66744140 |

If I use the command below, it looks like an execution result:

```sql
select longitude, latitude, st_astext(geom)
from geo_table;
```

| longitude | latitude | st_astext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 127.72793149 | 34.91585546 | MULTIPOLYGON(((127.624612809679 34.8948459848629,127.641913874999 34.8774209330787,127.703437082713 34.9180097593608,127.690046263045 34.9336415616824,127.624612809679 34.8948459848629)),((127.703796190353 34.90937986879,127.705604937381 34.9318378556445,127.761676095264 34.9632237237197,127.791568869815 34.9141738946624,127.793158362217 34.8789693739502,127.703796190353 34.90937986879))) |

But I want to see the converted data without executing the command. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrip does not convert any data received from database, so if you don't want to use built-in function, you should store data in table using the format you like from the beginning.